# Calculate a date difference within a group variable, over rows of missing observations

Tags: sas, retain

In SAS, I have ID, Date1, and Date2 sorted by ascending ID, Date1, and Date2. The sort causes the missing Date2 values to be where they are, as desired. How can I calculate the Date2 difference between rows with valid dates and obtain the results displayed in D_Date2?

In words it is: BY ID, skip a missing date value in Date2, read the next valid date under it, subtract the earlier date from the later, and write the difference as D_Date2 to the row that has the valid Date2 value. Thanks.

```
Obs ID  Date1      Date2        D_Date2
1   1   20090815   20090818       .
2   1   20090815   20090818       0
3   1   20090816   20090820       2
4   1   20090816          .       .
5   1   20090816   20090820       0
6   2   20090101          .       .
7   2   20090105   20090105       .
8   2   20090105          .       .
9   2   20090105   20090106       1
10  2   20090105   20090110       4
11  3   20080720          .       .
12  3   20080720   20080917       .
13  3   20080720   20080918       1
14  3   20081010          .       .
15  3   20081010   20080925       7
16  3   20081010   20080925       0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you could use `retain`, but I'd use the `lag` function. The key here is to understand that the `lag` function does *not* necessarily return the value from the previous row. If it follows an `if` condition, the `lag` function returns the value from the last row where the condition was true.

I like doing these things step-by-step for clarity. First I create a new variable `ldate2` that contains the date that is to be subtracted to get the desired difference, then I perform the subtraction.

```
data want;
  set have;
  if not missing(date2) then do;
    ldate2 = lag(date2);
    if id ne lag(id) then ldate2 = .;
  end;
  d_date2 = date2 - ldate2;
run;
```

As rbet suggests, using a `dif` function is simpler. `dif` behaves like `lag`, except it subtracts the previous value from the current value, so there's no need to perform the subtraction separately:

```
data want;
  set have;
  if not missing(date2) then do;
    d_date2 = dif(date2);
    if id ne lag(id) then d_date2 = .;
  end;
run;
```